# Dapper, Lambda expressions and returning the correct mapped fields

Tags: c#, lambda, dapper

I have a project that does not allow us to change the SPROCS, but I wanted to use something to automatically map the datareader rows to a POCO class.
In came Dapper to the rescue. For the most part it works great, but in some cases where I need to populate nested classes.
For example, I have this model

```
public class Account
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    /* Removed for brevity */

    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

my respository just looked like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Lists a range of items
/// </summary>
/// <param name="storedProcedureName">The name of the SPROC to execute</param>
/// <param name="parameters">The parameters needed for the SPROC</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<IList<T>> ListAsync(string storedProcedureName, OracleDynamicParameters parameters = null)
{
    return await ExecuteReaderAsync(storedProcedureName, parameters);
}

/// <summary>
/// Private method for executing a reader and returning the results as a list
/// </summary>
/// <param name="storedProcedureName">The name of the SPROC to execute</param>
/// <param name="parameters">The parameters needed for the SPROC</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<IList<T>> ExecuteReaderAsync(string storedProcedureName, OracleDynamicParameters parameters = null)
{

    // Init command
    InitializeCommand(storedProcedureName, parameters);

    // Dynamically populate our list
    var list = await this._connection.QueryAsync<T>(storedProcedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    // Dispose
    DisposeCommand();

    // Return our list
    return list.ToList();
}
```

which can be called from any service a bit like this:

```
return await Repository.ListAsync("IBPA_ORDERS.readLines", parameters);
```

Like I said, this works fine for a POCO class with no child classes, but as you can see, the **Account** model has a **Contact**.
Apparently you can get the contact populated using **Lambda expressions** like this:

```
.Select(x => new Account
{
    AccountNumber = x.AccountNumber 
    Contact = new Contact 
    {
        FirstName = x.Firstname,
        LastName = x.LastName
    }
});
```

So, I am trying to update my Repository method to handle that.
So far I have this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Private method for executing a reader and returning the results as a list
/// </summary>
/// <param name="storedProcedureName">The name of the SPROC to execute</param>
/// <param name="parameters">The parameters needed for the SPROC</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<IList<T>> ExecuteReaderAsync(string storedProcedureName, OracleDynamicParameters parameters = null, Func<dynamic, T> query = null)
{

    // Init command
    InitializeCommand(storedProcedureName, parameters);

    // Get our models
    var models = await this._connection.QueryAsync(storedProcedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    // If we supply a query, use it. Otherwise cast the result as our type
    var results = query == null ? models.Select(m => (T)m) : models.Select(query);

    // Dispose
    DisposeCommand();

    // Return our list
    return results.ToList();
}
```

But I am not sure if that is correct.
I have tried to call it like this:

```
// Execute and return our acctuons
return await Repository.ListAsync("IBPA_ACCOUNTSS.LIST", parameters, m => new Account {
    // LineRef = /* m is dynamic */
});
```

Because **m** is dynamic, I can't actually assign any properties.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Should `ExecuteReaderAsync` look like `ExecuteReaderAsync<T>`?  As far as I can tell by looking at this, it should work.  When you say you're struggling to call, what do you mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: updated my question to explain the issue a bit more

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little bit confused, but *I think* what you're asking is if you can have Dapper perform the deserialization so that `Account.Contact` is populated correctly.

If the returned columns are ordered such that all of the `Account` properties are first, and all of the `Contact` properties follow, then you can use Dapper's [Multi Mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping) feature.

For example:

```
Func<Account, Contact, Account> map = (a, c) => { a.Contact = c; return a; };

var results = conn.Query<Account, Contact, Account>(
    sql: storedProcedureName,
    map: map,
    splitOn: "FirstName",
    param: parameters,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

In the above code, Dapper is expecting to start by deserialiazing an `Account`. Then, when it reaches a column named "FirstName", it will start deserializing into a `Contact`. Once it's done, it will call `map` which will combine all of the deserialized types into just a single return value (`Account`).

The type arguments can be seen as: `<DeserializeType1, DeserializeType2, ..., ReturnType>`.

The `splitOn` argument defaults to "Id" because that's commonly the first column name of any table. I believe splitOn also accepts a comma-delimited list of column names, which might be handy if you're combining more than two tables, and the split columns are different.

---

If the results from the query/SProc are not in any particular order (say it returned columns in the order `FirstName`, `AccountNumber`, `LastName`), then Dapper's not going to be able to help you there.